# SQL ORDER BY showing single value repeatedly

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I am working in PHP and this is the script from SQL database and I want to display names alphabetically but when I use order by its only showing one name from `FIRM_NAME` list. I have also attached image. please help thank you.

```
 else {
   $register=" select * from REGISTRATION_TABLE  where REG_ID='".$reg."'";
   $register="SELECT * FROM REGISTRATION_TABLE GROUP BY FIRM_NAME ";
   $exereg = $con->query($register);
   $resreg=$exereg->fetch_assoc();
   // while($resreg= mysqli_fetch_array($exereg)){
     $user=$resreg['FIRM_NAME'];
   // }
   echo '<option value='.$reg.'>'.$user.'</option>';
 }
 //echo '<option>'.$user.'</option>';
}
```

[Image of results i m getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNgf9.png)

Comment: In the code you attached, the query has `GROUP BY`, not `ORDER BY`

Comment: Sorry but even if i do ORDER YB its showing same results